# sendTransaction never resolves on web3.js 1.0.0 beta49 - beta52

Tags: web3js, dapps, dapp-development

My plain vanilla `sendTransaction` doesn't ever resolve on `ganache` with web3js 1.0.0 beta52:

```
async function sendTx() {
  const receipt = await web3.eth
    .sendTransaction({
      to: "0x1...",
      from: "0x2...",
      value: web3.utils.toWei("0.1", "ether")
    });

   return receipt;
```

[Here is a barebone test script](https://gist.github.com/szerintedmi/251b5d5739888ad595548625c8d5d424) which should work on a "blank" ganache.

The script resolves on web3js beta48 although confirmations are not received (which might be a related issue?).

I also raised [an issue in web3.js repo](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2652) but it has been closed.

Does it work for you? What's wrong with my script?